# MutableLiveData setValue: Unexpected behavior in Activity's onCreate

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle

I'm toying with MutableLiveData's methods to figure out what triggers the observer and what doesn't.

Right now, I have this Activity:

```
class ActivityA : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val liveData = MutableLiveData<Int>().apply { this.value = 10 }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        liveData.observe(this, Observer {
            Log.v("ActivityA", "liveData = $it")
        })
        Log.v("ActivityA", "liveData = ${liveData.value}")
        liveData.value = 11
        liveData.postValue(12)
        liveData.value = 13
    }
}
```

The output is the following:

```
liveData = 10
liveData = 13
liveData = 12
```

Shouldn't it be this?

```
liveData = 10
liveData = 11
liveData = 13
liveData = 12
```

Comment: it seems maybe he just copied that answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51299641/difference-of-setvalue-postvalue-in-mutablelivedata

Comment: Can you move last three line to onStart method and try again ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that ***`livedata` `observer` is not active***. because of this when you do `liveData.value = 11`, this value doesn't get posted to the `observer`.
and subsequently when you do `liveData.value = 13` it `overrides` the value 11.

To check if your live data has any active observers, you can do `liveData.hasActiveObservers()`

***Docs clearly state that `setValue` only dispatches if there are any active observers***

> void ***setValue*** (T value)
>
> Sets the value. ***If there are active observers,*** the value will be
>   dispatched to them.

#### ***But why your observer is not active?***

When you set a value, `LiveData` internally uses `ObserverWrapper`'s  `shouldBeActive` method to check if a specific observer is active .

and when you use `observe` method to register your `observer`,  the  `observer` is wrapped in a `LifecycleBoundObserver` (subclass of `ObserverWrapper`) which defines its `shouldBeActive` as follows.

```
@Override
boolean shouldBeActive() {
   return mOwner.getLifecycle().getCurrentState().isAtLeast(STARTED);
}
```

***The part that matters is*** `.isAtLeast(STARTED)`, here `STARTED` is of type [Lifecycle.State](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Lifecycle.State), and its documentation has following to say about it.

> Started state for a LifecycleOwner. For an Activity, this state is
>   reached in two cases:
>
> ***after onStart call;***
>
> ***right before onPause call.***

and because you register `observer` in `onCreate`, it doesn't become active right away and hence the problem.

For verification you can also use the `observeForever` (***please read its documentation, it differs greatly from `observe`***) method to register your `observer`. because this method makes the `observer` `active` instantly, you will see the output that you expect.

```
liveData.observeForever {
    Log.v("ActivityA", "liveData = $it")
}
```

Comment: What is still strange about this is that if you remove the `postValue(12)` and the `setValue = 13`, then it WILL print 11, so it DOES have an observer when you do `setValue = 11` but only if you dont `postValue(12)`?

Comment: Actually that makes sense, its just getting over ridden before it gets an active observer, but the observer isn't active when its set to 11, you're right

Comment: Yes, Observer only becomes active if the lifecycle is started.