# Fragment testing: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, android-fragmentscenario

I'm struggling for a certain amount of time so I decided to ask for help here...
I'm using almost the as same architecture as Google sample: [GithubBrowserSample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample).

In the test of one of my fragment (androidTest) I encounter this error:

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:8191)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1420)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:24454)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:24454)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:24454)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:24454)
at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.requestLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:3028)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:24454)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.requestLayout(RecyclerView.java:4412)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$RecyclerViewDataObserver.triggerUpdateProcessor(RecyclerView.java:5582)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$RecyclerViewDataObserver.onItemRangeInserted(RecyclerView.java:5557)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$AdapterDataObservable.notifyItemRangeInserted(RecyclerView.java:12278)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(RecyclerView.java:7498)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.AdapterListUpdateCallback.onInserted(AdapterListUpdateCallback.java:42)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.AsyncListDiffer.submitList(AsyncListDiffer.java:283)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.AsyncListDiffer.submitList(AsyncListDiffer.java:231)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter.submitList(ListAdapter.java:128)
at com.maximesarrato.lafayapp.ui.training.TrainingListFragment$onViewCreated$3.onChanged(TrainingListFragment.kt:112)
at com.maximesarrato.lafayapp.ui.training.TrainingListFragment$onViewCreated$3.onChanged(TrainingListFragment.kt:39)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:131)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:149)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:307)
at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$1.run(LiveData.java:91)
at androidx.arch.core.executor.testing.InstantTaskExecutorRule$1.postToMainThread(InstantTaskExecutorRule.java:43)
at androidx.arch.core.executor.ArchTaskExecutor.postToMainThread(ArchTaskExecutor.java:101)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.postValue(LiveData.java:291)
at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.postValue(MutableLiveData.java:45)
at com.maximesarrato.lafayapp.ui.training.TrainingListFragmentTest.testTrainingListLoaded(TrainingListFragmentTest.kt:119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:80)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:392)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2189)
```

This error occurs on this part of the code, when I submit data to my ListAdapter:

```
viewModel.trainingsLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { result ->
    result?.data?.let {
        // Error occurs here
        adapter.submitList(it)
    }
})
```

This error occurs only when the list is not empty... I didn't encountered any errors when using the application but only during tests.

Here is the source code of my test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class TrainingListFragmentTest {
    @get:Rule
    var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val executorRule = TaskExecutorWithIdlingResourceRule()

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val countingAppExecutors = CountingAppExecutorsRule()

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val dataBindingIdlingResourceRule = DataBindingIdlingResourceRule()

    private val navController = mock<NavController>()
    private val trainingsLiveData = MutableLiveData<Resource<List<Training>>>()
    private val isPremiumLiveData = MutableLiveData<PremiumAccount>()
    private val trainingDeletedLiveData = MutableLiveData<Event<Boolean>>()
    private val navigateToCreateTrainingLiveData = MutableLiveData<Event<Boolean>>()
    private val navigateToExerciseListLiveData = MutableLiveData<Event<Training>>()
    private lateinit var viewModel: TrainingListViewModel

    @Before
    fun init() {
        viewModel = mock(TrainingListViewModel::class.java)
        val trainingListFragment = TrainingListFragment()
        trainingListFragment.viewModelFactory = ViewModelUtil.createFor(viewModel)
        trainingListFragment.appExecutors = countingAppExecutors.appExecutors

        trainingListFragment.viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.observeForever { viewLifecycleOwner ->
            if (viewLifecycleOwner != null) {
                Navigation.setViewNavController(trainingListFragment.requireView(), navController)
            }
        }

        `when`(viewModel.trainingsLiveData).thenReturn(trainingsLiveData)
        `when`(viewModel.isPremium).thenReturn(isPremiumLiveData)
        `when`(viewModel.trainingDeleted).thenReturn(trainingDeletedLiveData)
        `when`(viewModel.navigateToCreateTraining).thenReturn(navigateToCreateTrainingLiveData)
        `when`(viewModel.navigateToExerciseList).thenReturn(navigateToExerciseListLiveData)

        val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer(themeResId = R.style.Theme_LafayWorkbook) {
            trainingListFragment
        }
        dataBindingIdlingResourceRule.monitorFragment(scenario)
        scenario.onFragment { fragment ->
            Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController)
            fragment.binding.trainingListRv.itemAnimator = null
            fragment.disableProgressBarAnimations()
        }
    }

    /**
     * Verify that when data is loading then Progress bar is displayed
     * and Helper text is not displayed.
     *
     */
    @Test
    // Works
    fun testLoading() {
        trainingsLiveData.postValue(Resource.loading(null))
        onView(withId(R.id.trainingProgressBar)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
        onView(withId(R.id.trainingHelperTextView)).check(matches(not(isDisplayed())))
    }

    /**
     * Verify that when data is loaded and correspond to an empty list then Progress
     * bar is not displayed and Helper text is displayed.
     *
     */
    @Test
    // Works
    fun testEmptyListLoaded() {
        trainingsLiveData.postValue(Resource.success(listOf()))
        onView(withId(R.id.trainingProgressBar)).check(matches(not(isDisplayed())))
        onView(withId(R.id.trainingHelperTextView)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }

    /**
     * Checks helper text disappears and list of Training is correctly displayed
     *
     */
    @Test
    // This test doesn't work :(
    fun testTrainingListLoaded() {
        val trainings = createTrainings(
            3,
            createExercises(2)
        )
        trainingsLiveData.postValue(Resource.success(trainings.toMutableList()))
        onView(withId(R.id.trainingHelperTextView)).check(matches(not(isDisplayed())))
        onView(listMatcher().atPosition(0)).check(matches(hasDescendant(withText("Level 1"))))
    }
}
```

Do you guys have an idea about why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: It's probably the `InstantTaskExecutorRule` that is getting in your way. Removing it might fix it. Though you might want to run your code on the main thread using the Instrumentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are setting the value directly. Use `postValue` like the other tests:

```kotlin
    fun testTrainingListLoaded() {
        val trainings = createTrainings(
            3,
            createExercises(2)
        )
        trainingsLiveData.postValue(Resource.success(trainings.toMutableList()))
        onView(withId(R.id.trainingHelperTextView)).check(matches(not(isDisplayed())))
        onView(listMatcher().atPosition(0)).check(matches(hasDescendant(withText("Level 1"))))
    }
```

To see what is the difference between `postValue` and `setValue` you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51299641/difference-of-setvalue-postvalue-in-mutablelivedata).

> To summarize, the key difference would be:
>
> setValue() method must be called from the main thread. But if you need
>   set a value from a background thread, postValue() should be used.

Comment: I already tried this but it doesn't work either...
I updated my code with postValue and with the whole error.
Thanks for your answer anyway!

Answer (score 1):

This issue is linked to: [FragmentScenario doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61433558/fragmentscenario-doesnt-work-as-expected) and has been successfully solved!

I should not have use the rule IntantTaskExecutorRule:

```
@get:Rule
var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

And indeed without this rule I should have use `postValue` instead of `setValue` as Mohammad said. 
Also, as mentioned in the other question I asked and linked to this post the main issue was related to variable shadowing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61449895/9578385

Thanks for your help!