# FragmentScenario doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, android-fragmentscenario

I'm using almost the as same architecture as Google sample: [GithubBrowserSample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample).

This field is injected in my Fragment class:

```
@Inject
lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

val viewModel: TrainingListViewModel by viewModels {
    viewModelFactory
}
```

In all my fragments tests I got this error which corresponds to a field that is instantiated by injection:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property viewModelFactory has not been initialized
at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.runOnMainSync(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:441)
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.onActivity(ActivityScenario.java:564)
at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario.internalLaunch(FragmentScenario.java:300)
at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario.launchInContainer(FragmentScenario.java:282)
at com.maximesarrato.lafayapp.ui.training.TrainingListFragmentTest.init(TrainingListFragmentTest.kt:213)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:76)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:392)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2189)
Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property viewModelFactory has not been initialized
at com.maximesarrato.lafayapp.ui.training.TrainingListFragment.getViewModelFactory(TrainingListFragment.kt:41)
at com.maximesarrato.lafayapp.ui.training.TrainingListFragment$viewModel$2.invoke(TrainingListFragment.kt:49)
at com.maximesarrato.lafayapp.ui.training.TrainingListFragment$viewModel$2.invoke(TrainingListFragment.kt:39)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:52)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:41)
at com.maximesarrato.lafayapp.ui.training.TrainingListFragment.getViewModel(Unknown Source:7)
at com.maximesarrato.lafayapp.ui.training.TrainingListFragmentTest$init$$inlined$launchFragmentInContainer$1.instantiate(FragmentScenario.kt:114)
at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$1.perform(FragmentScenario.java:310)
at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$1.perform(FragmentScenario.java:301)
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.lambda$onActivity$2$ActivityScenario(ActivityScenario.java:551)
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario$$Lambda$4.run(Unknown Source:4)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.app.Instrumentation$SyncRunnable.run(Instrumentation.java:2207)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

This happens when I set my fragment like this with FragmentScenario:

```
viewModel = mock(TrainingListViewModel::class.java)

val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer(themeResId = R.style.Theme_LafayWorkbook) {
    TrainingListFragment().apply {
        appExecutors = countingAppExecutors.appExecutors
        viewModelFactory = ViewModelUtil.createFor(viewModel)
    }
}

dataBindingIdlingResourceRule.monitorFragment(scenario)
scenario.onFragment { fragment ->
    Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController)
    fragment.binding.trainingListRv.itemAnimator = null
    fragment.disableProgressBarAnimations()
}
```

But when I setup the Fragment before using it with FragmentScenario it works:

```
viewModel = mock(TrainingListViewModel::class.java)
val trainingListFragment = TrainingListFragment()
trainingListFragment.viewModelFactory = ViewModelUtil.createFor(viewModel)
trainingListFragment.appExecutors = countingAppExecutors.appExecutors

trainingListFragment.viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.observeForever { viewLifecycleOwner ->
    if (viewLifecycleOwner != null) {
        Navigation.setViewNavController(trainingListFragment.requireView(), navController)
    }
}

val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer(themeResId = R.style.Theme_LafayWorkbook) {
    trainingListFragment
}
```

Here is the source code of my test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class TrainingListFragmentTest {
    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val executorRule = TaskExecutorWithIdlingResourceRule()

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val countingAppExecutors = CountingAppExecutorsRule()

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val dataBindingIdlingResourceRule = DataBindingIdlingResourceRule()

    private val navController = mock<NavController>()
    private val trainingsLiveData = MutableLiveData<Resource<List<Training>>>()
    private val isPremiumLiveData = MutableLiveData<PremiumAccount>()
    private val trainingDeletedLiveData = MutableLiveData<Event<Boolean>>()
    private val navigateToCreateTrainingLiveData = MutableLiveData<Event<Boolean>>()
    private val navigateToExerciseListLiveData = MutableLiveData<Event<Training>>()
    private lateinit var viewModel: TrainingListViewModel

    @Before
    fun init() {
        viewModel = mock(TrainingListViewModel::class.java)
        val trainingListFragment = TrainingListFragment()
        trainingListFragment.viewModelFactory = ViewModelUtil.createFor(viewModel)
        trainingListFragment.appExecutors = countingAppExecutors.appExecutors

        trainingListFragment.viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.observeForever { viewLifecycleOwner ->
            if (viewLifecycleOwner != null) {
                Navigation.setViewNavController(trainingListFragment.requireView(), navController)
            }
        }

        `when`(viewModel.trainingsLiveData).thenReturn(trainingsLiveData)
        `when`(viewModel.isPremium).thenReturn(isPremiumLiveData)
        `when`(viewModel.trainingDeleted).thenReturn(trainingDeletedLiveData)
        `when`(viewModel.navigateToCreateTraining).thenReturn(navigateToCreateTrainingLiveData)
        `when`(viewModel.navigateToExerciseList).thenReturn(navigateToExerciseListLiveData)

        val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer(themeResId = R.style.Theme_LafayWorkbook) {
            trainingListFragment
        }
        dataBindingIdlingResourceRule.monitorFragment(scenario)
        scenario.onFragment { fragment ->
            Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController)
            fragment.binding.trainingListRv.itemAnimator = null
            fragment.disableProgressBarAnimations()
        }
    }

}
```

Do you guys have an idea about why this is happening and how I can fix it?
I'm really struggling on this :(

Comment: Can you include your `TrainingListFragment` code? Specifically where are you accessing `viewModelFactory` and which line is throwing the exception you're getting

Comment: @ianhanniballake I edited my post with it!

Comment: Also edited with the complete exception...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is due to [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

When you write this code

```
viewModel = mock(TrainingListViewModel::class.java)

val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer(themeResId = R.style.Theme_LafayWorkbook) {
    TrainingListFragment().apply {
        appExecutors = countingAppExecutors.appExecutors
        viewModelFactory = ViewModelUtil.createFor(viewModel)
    }
}
```

The `ViewModelUtil.createFor(viewModel)` is **not** using the `viewModel` variable that you've created with `mock` above, but is instead using the `viewModel` variable **within your `TrainingListFragment`. This is because you are using `apply { }`, which means that the scope that the code applies to is the fragment itself - its effectively as if your code was within that fragment itself so `viewModel` is really `TrainingListViewModel.this.viewModel`.

This is why your error message says

```
at com.maximesarrato.lafayapp.ui.training.TrainingListFragment.getViewModel(Unknown Source:7)
at com.maximesarrato.lafayapp.ui.training.TrainingListFragmentTest$init$$inlined$launchFragmentInContainer$1.instantiate(FragmentScenario.kt:114)
```

You're calling `getViewModel()` i.e.., accessing the `viewModel` property from within your `instantiate` block.

The easiest solution is to just use a different variable name for your mock viewModel instead of using the same name of `viewModel`. If it was named `mockViewModel`, then it calling `ViewModelUtil.createFor(mockViewModel)` would correctly reference your mock ViewModel since there wouldn't be any variable from your fragment with that same name.

The other option is to use `also` instead of `apply`:

```
viewModel = mock(TrainingListViewModel::class.java)

val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer(themeResId = R.style.Theme_LafayWorkbook) {
    TrainingListFragment().also { fragment ->
        fragment.appExecutors = countingAppExecutors.appExecutors
        fragment.viewModelFactory = ViewModelUtil.createFor(viewModel)
    }
}
```

`also`, like `apply`, always returns the original object - your `TrainingListFragment` (this is correct and what you want to return).

However, when using `also` you have to name the variable you're operating on (here I use `fragment` rather than the default `it`) and you need to specifically use `fragment.viewModel` if you wanted to refer to something within the fragment variable. Again, without any name shadowing, in this case `viewModel` would point to the only `viewModel` variable in scope - your mock ViewModel.

Comment: Oh man indeed it was that... thank you! Really simpler than I thought.
I searched the issue anywhere else but not there... Thanks for this lesson Ian!