# LiveData not firing when Inside Network Change Callbacks in Android View Model - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

Trying to listen to a Connection call back using Live Data.
The Callbacks "onAvailable" and "onLost" are fired, but the "postValue" inside the ViewModel is not fired. It is first only once when the AppViewModel is initialized and the init is called only once.
When I move the postData outside the network callbacks, it fires.
Any help is appreciated.

```
class AppViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private var connectivityManager =
        application.applicationContext.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    var wifiStatusListener = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

    var callback: NetworkCallback =
        object : NetworkCallback() {
            override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                wifiStatusListener.postValue(true) // never calls.
                logI(TAG, "onAvailable ${network.describeContents()}")
            }

            override fun onLost(network: Network) {
                wifiStatusListener.postValue(false) // never calls.
                logE(TAG, "onLost ${network.describeContents()}")
            }
        }



    init {
        logI(TAG, "View Model Initialized")
        viewModelScope.launch {
            initWiFiStatusCheckListener()
        }
    }
```

```
 // called from init in ViewModel
 connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(callback)
```

In Activity, this is how View model is initialized.
The log below is called only once for the first time

```
logI(TAG, "Wifi Listener $it")
```

```
 appViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(AppViewModel::class.java)
 appViewModel.wifiStatusListener.observe(this, Observer {
            logI(TAG, "Wifi Listener $it")
        })
```

Comment: Seems there is nothing wrong with the code. Can you help to attach more complete code on `registerDefaultNetworkCallback()` and on observe `wifiStatusListener` in the activity?

Answer (score 1):

You should observe the change of connectivity in Activity or Fragment. Then in each call back for the changes, you pass your callback from ViewModel to handle this. And you don't need to use the `wifiStatusListener`  to observe change. Just get the property inside the callback to handle.

Notice that you should not pass the application context to the ViewModel. Just use current context in the Activity.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but do you know why the postData is not triggered inside the Network Change callbacks.
Thanks.

Comment: I had also created a class extending the LiveData, still the postData won't fire inside the network callbacks.

Comment: Did you try the `setValue()` instead of the `postValue()`. The postData is triggered, but in background thread. Reference here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51299641/difference-of-setvalue-postvalue-in-mutablelivedata

Comment: I tried both. didn't work.

Comment: Just discovered an artical that you can refer : https://medium.com/@kiitvishal89/android-listening-to-connectivity-changes-the-correct-way-a614f0d6d2af

Answer (score 1):

If your `ViewModel` is using `Context` in any form I typically make the `ViewModel` follow along the `AndroidLifeCycle` instead of storing `Context` in the `ViewModel`.

```
//in ViewModel
fun onResume(context : Context){
    var connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(callback)
}
fun onPause(context : Context){
    var connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(callback)
}



//in Activity/Fragment
fun onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    viewModel.onResume(requireContext())
}
fun onPause(){
    viewModel.onPause(requireContext())
    super.onPause();
}
```

You could also store the `ConnectivityManager` in the `Activity/Fragment` and just pass it instead of context but don't store it in the `ViewModel`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The Problem here is postData not firing from ViewModel. Any idea why it didn't fire in Network callback in the View Model?

Comment: How are you determining that the events are not firing? Are you connecting/disconnecting to wifi or a cellular network? My answer was more of a fix to stop storing context inside a static resource (ie ViewModel) which could cause problems. It seems the problem you are having was not caused by that.

Comment: I am connecting and disconnecting the wifi and the callbacks are firing, but the postValue is not firing after the first time.

Comment: If your doing this from anything other than an `Activity` try swapping the lifecycle owner of the `ViewModel` to the `Activity` `ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(AppViewModel::class.java)`