# Why LiveData doesn't pass event if called from the callback?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In my ViewModel I have such a code:

```
    ...
    private val billingClientLifecycle: BillingClientLifecycle
    private val _isBillingConnectionReady = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val isBillingConnectionReady: LiveData<Boolean> = _isBillingConnectionReady
    ...
    
    init {
        ...
        billingClientLifecycle.setPurchaseUpdateListener(
            object : IapPurchasesUpdatedListener {
                ...

                override fun isBillingConnected(state: Boolean) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Billing connection state is: $state")
                    _isBillingConnectionReady.value = state
                }
            }
        )

        billingClientLifecycle.createBillingConnection(getApplication())
        ...
    }
    
    ...
```

So here I have a `billingClientLifecycle` object and in `init()` I invoke `createBillingConnection` method I see that I get a response in the callback `isBillingConnected` and I see that `_isBillingConnectionReady` livedata is being called, however, I don't get this event in my fragment where I subscribed on this event.

What am I missing here? Why live data doesn't pass the event? Could it be somehow because the callback captures the values?

Comment: I don't see any reason this wouldn't work in the code you've posted so far. Maybe you can also show where you observe the live data.

Comment: have you tested with LiveData.postValue() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found a solution, the problem is here, to be honest I totaly forgot about these methods diff.

[Link to the orig SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51299672/5709159) :

Based on the documentation:

[setValue()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData#setValue(T)):

> Sets the value. If there are active observers, the value will be
> dispatched to them. This method must be called from the main thread.

[postValue()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData#postValue(T)):

> Posts a task to a main thread to set the given value. If you called this method multiple times before a main thread executed a posted task, only the last value would be dispatched.

To summarize, the key difference would be:

`setValue()` method must be called from the main thread. But if you need set a value from a background thread, `postValue()` should be used.

Comment: I don't see why this is relevant, since you are setting the value from the main thread, the IapPurchasesUpdatedListener.